# Custom view above table view cell with UIContextMenu

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, contextmenu

I am trying to implement something like this:

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ0yr.png)]

I have already added contextual menu below my tableView cell. Now I want to add reaction view above the cell. I am unable to find any solution for this. This is how my code is for contextual menu :
In tableview's `contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt` method I have added menu like this:

```
let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
    return menu
}
```

What I have already tried is to use PreviewProvider, but with this new view controller appears and cell got disappeared. Didnt find any library for this as well.